# Фреймы в yii как использовать?

Tags: yii

Товарищи знатоки, подскажите, как запустить страницу в фрейме?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну идем в нужное представление. Например для главной `/views/site/index.php` и там пишем

```
<iframe src="http://yandex.ru"></iframe>
```

Comment: вы же знаете, что это не работает?

Comment: Как проявляется "не работает"? Не вижу причин для того, чтобы что-то мешало.

Comment: @dimka3210, @anunak имеет в виду заголовок X-Frame-Options:DENY. С яндексом действительно работать не будет, но зачем такой категоричный ответ давать, будто это не работает вообще в принципе - не знаю.

Comment: да, действительно работает, у меня, видать, опенсервер к инету доступа не имеет, а так локальные странички - на ура.